# Ruby - How to not overwrite instance variables in methods?

Tags: ruby

Say that we have this class:

```
class Hello
  def hello
    @hello
  end

  def hello=(hello)
    @hello = hello
  end

  def other_method
    hello = 'hi!'
    ...
  end
end
```

In this case,

```
h = Hello.new
h.other_method
puts h.hello
```

will write 'hi!', due to the interpretation of `hello =` as `self.hello =`. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour, giving to the `hello =` declaration a method-local scope (as, for example , `var hello =` would do with javascript code)?

**EDIT** I'm sorry, I was sure I had a problem for this reason! But now I have two other questions!

1. why `hello =` is not interpreted as `self.hello =`??? it is declared as an instance method...
2. why, even if I write

```
...
  def other_method
    self.hello = 'hi!'
  end
end
h = Hello.new
h.other_method
puts h.hello
```

it returns `nil`??? now it should be an explicit assignment!

Thank you for the patience, I'm a bit confused! :-/

Comment: Have you even checked what does this code output before asking the question?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the followups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this will **not** print hi! because `hello = 'hi!'` in `other_method` assigns to a local variable and is not interpreted as `self.hello=`.

If this is not the behaviour that you're seeing then there must be something else specific to your code that you haven't included in the question.

---

Answers to the follow up questions:

1. Within the body of a method `identifier = value` assigns a local variable (no method lookup is performed (so it's doesn't matter that there's a `hello=` method. You need the explicit `self.` to invoke the method.
2. When you write `puts h.hello` it prints 'hi!' which is the return value of `h.hello` but then returns `nil` which is the return value of `puts`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class Hello
irb(main):002:1> def hello
irb(main):003:2>   @hello
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> def hello=(hello)
irb(main):006:2>   @hello = hello
irb(main):007:2> end
irb(main):008:1> def other_method
irb(main):009:2>   self.hello = 'hi!'
irb(main):010:2> end
irb(main):011:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> h = Hello.new
=> #<Hello:0xb746b7cc>
irb(main):013:0> h.other_method
=> "hi!"
irb(main):014:0> puts h.hello
hi!
=> nil
```